# Rails Zeitwerk `Wrong constant name` for javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, zeitwerk

Using Rails 6

I have a folder like so `app/client/javascript/config/editor/syntax-highlighting`

2 files in there.

`app/client/javascript/config/editor/syntax-highlighting/math-mode.js`
`app/client/javascript/config/editor/syntax-highlighting/units-regex.js`

When I deploy to production there error message is:

`Wrong constant name Syntax-Highlighting inferred by Module from directory (Zeitwerk::NameError)`

And it gives a path to that directory.
`app/client/javascript/config/editor/syntax-highlighting`

What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 4):

You’re placing JavaScript in a directory that gets eager loaded by Zeitwork in production. Either move the JS to an asset-specific directory (like app/assets for Sprockets or app/javascript for Webpacker) or configure Rails to ignore it:

```rb
# config/application.rb

Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(Rails.root.join('app/path/to/dir'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue recently with rails/webpacker when including a hyphen in my directory name.

These worked:
webpacker/images/img.jpg
webpacker/images/photos/img.jpg

This caused the error
webpacker/images/compound-word/img.jpg

I didn't have time to get to the bottom of it so I just changed it to
webpacker/images/compoundword/img.jpg